# Angular Stop Propagation of Different Event

Tags: angular, click, stoppropagation

In my Angular 4 application, I have a parent component with a (dblclick) handler and a child component with a (click) handler.

component.html

```
<mat-list (dblclick)="goBack()">
    <button (click)="add($event)"> Add </button>
</mat-list>
```

component.ts

```
add(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    doSomething();
}
```

However, from what I've seen, stopPropagation only stops events of the same type. In this example, if someone double clicks the button, it calls the goBack() function.  If I change the parent component's event to a single (click) event, the propagation is stopped.

Is there anyway for me to block a (dblclick) in parent through the child's (click) event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to block (dblclick) when do single click right ?

Comment: How about using `EventEmitter` as `@output` from child which can be monitored in `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)` function of `parentComponent`. You cant control parent dblclick event but you can certainly set a `boolean` which can allow execution of `goBack()` function. I hope it has helped

Comment: That's a good idea. Unfortunately, I was imprecise with my question. The child is not an angular component, it's just an HTML button. If I was going to go this route, I would have to make it an actual component.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below. I think it's the simplest way.

`event.target` always refers to highest layer inside parent where event is assigned. Instead of nodeName, you can compare target by class, or id as well to be sure its a right button.

```
<mat-list (dblclick)="goBack($event)">
    <button (click)="add($event)"> Add </button>
</mat-list>

goBack(event){
    if(event.target.nodeName === "BUTTON"){
       return;
    }
    doSomething();
}

add(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    doSomething();
}
```

Here you have working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OELFbUY81m41I76R8mn6?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome, that will work, thanks. I'm assuming I can remove the stopPropagation from the add event then, as there is no (click) event on the parent