# mat-select multiselect option click only on checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-select, mat-option

I want to create a dropdown which has my mat-option with multiselect and have radio buttons on each mat-option.

The problem that I am facing is I cannot ideally click on radio buttons.
On clicking on any option the radio gets selected automatically and if I select another radio option it deselects the field.

Something like this

```
       <mat-option
        *ngFor="let property of filteredProperties | async"
        [value]="property"
        matTooltipClass="tooltip"
        matTooltipShowDelay="5000"
        [matTooltip]="property"
        (click)="loadPropertiesDetails(property)">
        {{ property }}

        <mat-radio-group formControlName="axis">
          <mat-radio-button
            class="radiobtn"
            value="Primary"
            >P</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button
            class="radiobtn"
            value="Secondry"
            >S</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>

      </mat-option>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQW5k.png)

Is there any way to achieve so ?

Comment: There are 2 components inside the option, from the image. 1. checkbox and 2. radio. I only see the radio. How are you setting the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add **event.stopPropagation()** on the Button event.
See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808915/angular-stop-propagation-of-different-event). That will stop the Click event on the button from also toggling the click event on the Multiselect.

Hope this helps!